# Activator.CreateInstance failing

Tags: c#

I have am creating an Instance dynamically using Activator.CreateInstance. However, it is saying object cannot be null on every attempt. Pasting the code below. Am I doing anything wrong?

Is there any problem if

> Activator.CreateInstance

replaces the conventional switch/case statements for determining the object type in the run-time? Thanks.

```
public abstract  class Base
{
    public abstract void Func();

}
public  class  Derived:Base
{
    public override void Func()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Derived First");
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Base
{
    public override void Func()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Derived Second");
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I was trying to make use of the overladed version 
    // where it takes the Type as parameter.
    BaseClass report = 
       (BaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Derived")); 
    report.Func();
}
```

Comment: why don't you use typeof() instead of Type.GetType()??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of the `typeName` parameter of [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
>   AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing
>   assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name
>   qualified by its namespace.

This means that you need to (at least) pass the namespace as well:

```
BaseClass report = (BaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("YourNamespace.Derived"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, `Type.GetType("Derived")` is almost certainly returning null - which would make it nothing to do with `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Check:

- Is `Derived` in the same assembly as the calling code? If not, use `Assembly.GetType` on the right assembly, or include the assembly name in the type name you're passing to `Type.GetType()`
- Is your type in a namespace? If so, you need to namespace-qualify it

Comment: Is there any problem if this method replaces the conventional switch/case statements for determining the object type in the run-time? Thanks.

Comment: In my program i am recieving an enum value from the server. that enum value will determine what object have to be created. eg: Mammal mb; switch(MammalType) : case Cat:  mb = new Cat(); break; case Dog: mb = new Dog(); I was asking if i can somehow retrieve the name of the enum value, i can use it construct the class object in a single statement rather than depending on the switch case statement. Is this approach having any drawback?

Comment: @logeeks: Well, it's slower and as you've found, more error prone. You could create a `Dictionary<EnumType, Type>` instead - that may well be a better idea. Or even a `Dictionary<EnumType, Func<BaseType>>` populated using lambda expressions.

Answer (score 3):

`Type.GetType("Derived"` cant find the type

Simeple change

```
BaseClass report = (BaseClass) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("Derived"));
```

to this

```
Base report = (Base)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Derived));
```

Comment: In that case, I guess `Base report = new Derived();` would be even simpler?

Comment: Yes, but i think this (the question) was only a sample.

Comment: I think so too, but I also think that a key point is that the type is not known at compile time. If it is (as in your answer), there is no need to use `Activator.CreateInstance` at all.

Comment: Is it type really unknown if using `typeof(Derived)`. It is clear that in the case of  `Type.GetType("Derived")` it is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

The [`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method is failing and returning null. See the parameters section of the previous link.

> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is in the currently executing assembly or in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to supply the type name qualified by its namespace.

Add the namespace before `"Derived"` and if the `Derived` class is in a different assembly, then add `", assemblyname"` to the end.

---

Note that if you aren't going to vary the string you pass into `GetType`, then you could just use `typeof(Derived)` (although in that case there isn't much point using `Activator.CreateInstance`).

Answer (score 0):

At Runtime, your GetType call will return `null`. You have to :

- either Precise your namespace
- or Use typeof